# Equivalent of `range` in Coq

Tags: coq

There is a function which is usually called `range` in other languages: it takes a natural `n`, and returns a list of naturals `[0,1,2,...,n-1]`. Does the Coq standard library have this function, and if so, what is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [`seq`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html#seq), although it's not literally what you ask for, since it receives two arguments: the starting point and the length. So `range n = seq 0 n`.